# UITableview paging crash aplication after loading 600 rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, pagination

I have a one major issue. I have implemented a uitable view with paging but when i reach to row 700 application crashed also sometimes it restart the ipad. So i tried every thing but i am not getting solution. this is my code.

```
#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
 return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (dataArray.count<[self.allRecordCount intValue])
    {
        return dataArray.count+1;
    }
 return dataArray.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if (dataArray.count<[self.allRecordCount intValue])
    {
        if (indexPath.row < dataArray.count) {
           return [self dataCellForIndexPath:indexPath tableview:tableView];
    } else {
        return [self loadingCell];
    }
}else{
    return [self dataCellForIndexPath:indexPath tableview:tableView];
}

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (cell.tag == kLoadingCellTag) {

    [self fillDataArray];
}
}
      - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

     return 150;
    }
#pragma mark PAGING_LOGIC
-(void)fillDataArray
 {
self.strStartPoint=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[dataArray count]];
self.strPageSize=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",kPageSize];
NSMutableArray *temp=[manager returnCallArray:self.strStartPoint NoofRecord:self.strPageSize];
for (Call *obj in temp)
{
    [dataArray addObject:obj];
}
[temp release];
[tbl reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)loadingCell {
UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                                  initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityIndicator.frame=CGRectMake(480.5f,52.5f , 45, 45);


    [cell addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator release];

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

     cell.tag = kLoadingCellTag;

 return cell;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)dataCellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath tableview:(UITableView *)table
{

 NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
 UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(table.tag == 0){

    //cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *lblCall;UILabel *lblCallText;UILabel *lblAirComment;UILabel *lblCustomerTxt;UILabel *lblProximityTxt;

    UILabel *lblNoOfMachineTxt;
    UILabel *lblCallReceiveTxt;
    UILabel *lblCallDueTxt;
if (cell==nil) {
 Call *temp = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
 lblCall = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,setY,220,20)];
        lblCall.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblCall.text = @"Call Priority/Type/Status";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblCall];
        [lblCall release];
 lblCallText = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220,setY,270,20)];
        lblCallText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


        lblCallText.tag = indexPath.row+100;
 [cell.contentView addSubview:lblCallText];
        [lblCallText release]; 
 lbl_strstatusChangeReason = [[UILabel alloc] init];/
 lbl_strstatusChangeReason.frame=CGRectMake(20,setY,800, labelSize5.height);
        lbl_strstatusChangeReason.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lbl_strstatusChangeReason.text = str_changeStatusReasoon;
        lbl_strstatusChangeReason.tag = indexPath.row + 200000;
        lbl_strstatusChangeReason.numberOfLines = 0;
        lbl_strstatusChangeReason.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        lbl_strstatusChangeReason.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_strstatusChangeReason];
 }
 return cell;
 }
```

This is my NSObject which i use for filling cell.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface Call : NSObject {

NSString *strType;
NSString *strTypePriority;
NSString *strCustomer;
NSString *strProximity;
 NSString *strETADateTime;

NSString *str480;
NSString *strAirComment;
NSString *strProblemDesc;
NSString *strNumberOfMachine;
NSString *strCallReceived;
NSString *strCallDue;
NSString *strAssignedTech;
  NSString *strAssignedTechName;
NSString *strDefaultTech;
  NSString *strDefaultTechName;
NSString *strDispatchedBy;
}
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strDispatchedToTechInterval;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strDispatchedToBranchInterval;

 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strDispatchToTechnicianDate;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strDispatchToTechnicianTime;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strDispatchToTechnicianFrom;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strDispatchToTechnicianBy;

 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strCallClosedDateAndTimeSorting;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strCallClosedDateAndTime;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strCallClosedDate;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strCallClosedTime;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strtotalAmount;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strtotalPartAmount;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strtotalChargeAmount;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strOriginatingFacility;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str_RecordVersionNumber;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str_CustomerLatitude;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str_CustomerLongitude;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strDiscount;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str_HdrComment1; 
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str_PrioritySortValue;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str_StatusChangeReason;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str_OnSiteDate;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str_Address;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str_Address1;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str_Address2;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str_City;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str_State;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str_Zip;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strStatus;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strTypePriority;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strCustomer;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strProximity;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str480;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strAirComment;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strProblemDesc;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strNumberOfMachine;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strCallReceived;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strCallDue;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strAssignedTech;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strDefaultTech;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strDispatchedBy;
 @end

 #import "Call.h"

 @implementation Call


 @synthesize strStatus;
 @synthesize strTypePriority;
 @synthesize strCustomer;
 @synthesize strProximity;
 @synthesize str480;
 @synthesize strAirComment;
 @synthesize strProblemDesc;
 @synthesize strNumberOfMachine;
 @synthesize strCallReceived;
 @synthesize strCallDue;
 @synthesize strAssignedTech;
 @synthesize strDefaultTech;
 @synthesize strDispatchedBy;

 @synthesize strCallNumber;
 @synthesize strHoldCall;
 @synthesize strOpenCall;
 @synthesize strLoactionId;
 @synthesize strCustomerName;
 @synthesize strContactName;
 @synthesize strPhoneNo;
 @synthesize strFirsMachine;
 @synthesize strMachineDone;
 @synthesize strDispatchedToBranch;
 @synthesize strDispatchedToTech;
 @synthesize strServiceDue;
 @synthesize strCallComment;
 @synthesize strDiscount;
 - (void)dealloc {

[strStatus release];
[strTypePriority release];
[strCustomer release];
[strProximity release];
[str480 release];
[strAirComment release];
[strProblemDesc release];
[strNumberOfMachine release];
[strCallReceived release];
[strCallDue release];
[strAssignedTech release];
[strDefaultTech release];
[strDispatchedBy release];
[strCallNumber release];
[strHoldCall release];
[strOpenCall release];
[strLoactionId release];
[strCustomerName release];
[strContactName release];
[strPhoneNo release];
[strFirsMachine release];
[strMachineDone release];
[strDispatchedToBranch release];
[strDispatchedToTech release];
[strServiceDue release];
[strCallComment release];
[strDiscount release];
[str_StatusChangeReason release];
 [super dealloc];
 }
```

and this is my method which i am using for filling array for paging.

```
 -(NSMutableArray *)returnCallArray:(NSString *)startPoint NoofRecord:(NSString *)noOfRecord
 {
[self initiateFMDB];
    NSMutableArray *aryCallFilterData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  //  NSMutableArray *finalArrayCall=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
@try {
    if(![db open]){
        NSLog(@"Could not open  DB");
    }
    else{
           resultset = [db executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select Call_HDR.*,Problem.Machine,Problem.ServiceStatusFlag,AssignTech.RepName AS AssignTechName,DefaultTech.RepName AS DefaultTechName,Problem.ProblemDescription AS ProblemDescription,Problem.SLAHours AS SLAHours,ARComment.CustARComments As CustARComments,SLAResponseCode.SLAResponse As SLAResponse from CALL_HDR LEFT  JOIN Branch_Reps as AssignTech ON CALL_HDR.RepID = AssignTech.RepID LEFT  JOIN Branch_Reps as DefaultTech ON CALL_HDR.AssignedServiceRep = DefaultTech.RepID LEFT  JOIN CALL_MACHINE as Problem ON CALL_HDR.CallNumber||'*001' = Problem.CallNumberWSeqnbr LEFT  JOIN Customers as ARComment ON CALL_HDR.LocationID = ARComment.LocationID LEFT  JOIN NA_Data as SLAResponseCode ON CALL_HDR.CustomerTypeCode = SLAResponseCode.NationalAccountCode where CALL_HDR.CallStatus IN ('%@','%@')  LIMIT  %@,%@ ",STATUS_CLOSED,STATUS_CANCELLED,startPoint,noOfRecord]];
    }
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception error for selectFromItemPhoto is %@",[e reason]);
}
if (!resultset) {
    NSLog(@"no result set fechted");
  }
  while ([resultset next]) {
     NSString *strCallPrioritySortValue = [resultset stringForColumn:@"PrioritySortValue"];
     NSString *strCallPriority = [resultset stringForColumn:@"CallPriority"];
     NSString *strCallType = [resultset stringForColumn:@"CallType"];
     NSString *strCallStatus = [resultset stringForColumn:@"CallStatus"];
     NSString *strCustomerName = [resultset stringForColumn:@"CustomerName"];
     NSString *strAdd1 = [resultset stringForColumn:@"Address1"];
     NSString *strAdd2 = [resultset stringForColumn:@"Address2"];
     NSString *strCity = [resultset stringForColumn:@"City"];
     NSString *strState = [resultset stringForColumn:@"State"];
     NSString *strZip = [resultset stringForColumn:@"Zip"];
     NSString *strCustomer=@"";
    ObjModel.strStsChgByRep=strStatusChgByRep;
    ObjModel.strCustomer = strCustomer;
    ObjModel.strStatus = strCallStatus;
    ObjModel.strHoldCall =strHoldCode;
    ObjModel.strProximity = @"";
    ObjModel.f_proximity = 0.0f;
    ObjModel.str480 = strStr480;
    ObjModel.strProblemDesc = strProbleDesc;
    ObjModel.strNumberOfMachine =strNumberOfMachine;
    ObjModel.strCallReceived = strCallReceive;
    ObjModel.strCallDue = strCallDue;
    ObjModel.strAssignedTech =  strAssignedTech;
    ObjModel.strDefaultTech = strDefaultTech;
    ObjModel.strDispatchedBy = strDispatchedBy;
    ObjModel.strCallNumber =  strCallNumber;
    ObjModel.n_CallNumber = [strCallNumber intValue];
    ObjModel.strLoactionId = strLoactionId;
    ObjModel.strContactName = strContactName;
    ObjModel.strCustomerName = strCustomerName;
    ObjModel.strPhoneNo = strPhoneNo;
    ObjModel.strDiscount = strDisct;
    ObjModel.strAirComment = strAirComment;
    ObjModel.strAssigntechName = strAssignedTechBy;
    ObjModel.strRepId = strRepId;
    ObjModel.str_Address1 = strAdd;
    ObjModel.str_StatusChangeReason = strStatusChangeReason;
    [aryCallFilterData addObject:ObjModel];
    [ObjModel release];
   }
 return aryCallFilterData;
}
```

So please review my code and suggest something so that i can resolve crash.

This is crash log:

```
Received memory warning.
2013-06-24 04:59:26.168 MFSS_PAGING_FACEBOOK[874:907] <FMDatabase: 0x2d8aa130> executeQuery: select Call_HDR.*,Problem.Machine,Problem.ServiceStatusFlag,AssignTech.RepName AS AssignTechName,DefaultTech.RepName AS DefaultTechName,Problem.ProblemDescription AS ProblemDescription,Problem.SLAHours AS SLAHours,ARComment.CustARComments As CustARComments,SLAResponseCode.SLAResponse As SLAResponse from CALL_HDR LEFT  JOIN Branch_Reps as AssignTech ON CALL_HDR.RepID = AssignTech.RepID LEFT  JOIN Branch_Reps as DefaultTech ON CALL_HDR.AssignedServiceRep = DefaultTech.RepID LEFT  JOIN CALL_MACHINE as Problem ON CALL_HDR.CallNumber||'*001' = Problem.CallNumberWSeqnbr LEFT  JOIN Customers as ARComment ON CALL_HDR.LocationID = ARComment.LocationID LEFT  JOIN NA_Data as SLAResponseCode ON CALL_HDR.CustomerTypeCode = SLAResponseCode.NationalAccountCode where CALL_HDR.CallStatus IN ('8','0')  LIMIT  700,100
```

Thanks

Comment: No, you are responsible for reasonably debugging first.  Don't just throw hundreds of lines of code on the Internet.  Work out where the problem is.  Start commenting out lines to see if it affects the situation, etc.

Comment: Are you getting some memory warning?

Comment: borrrden , I debuged this code lots of time and i clearly mentioned that after scrolling of 700 rows in table application get crashed. And my concern for posting this code is that is there any thing wrong in code or it may affect i taken a lots of strings in my nsobject or my data fetching method is incorrect. and if some one is looking in to it than he can easily figure out what is going wrong in code. any way thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: can you post the crash log? if the crash happens only for memory issue then it can't crash exactly 700 rows in a table. It will differ every time you run. May be their is something wrong. post the crash log.

Comment: Ashmin, I modified my question and added a crash log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reuse your cells. You have so many UITableViewCells loaded into memory and it crashes after a memory warning.

You cell identifier (index+row) create as many cells as 700, when you are loading 700 rows of data. The cell identifier should be unique to the number of cells shown in the screen, not more than that. Best is, you can have some other easy and non looping cell identifier. So cells are reused more efficiently.

Try to use the same UITableViewCell but change the labels and detailLabels matching with your information to show.

Comment: Yes karim, After posting code on stack over flow i made that change and now i can load 1000 rows easily but now i am facing a problem the height of each row changed and due to that rows are over lapped together. As i am thinking that CGSize constraintSize5 = CGSizeMake(800,MAXFLOAT);
                 CGSize labelSize5 = [str_changeStatusReasoon sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17] constrainedToSize:constraintSize5 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; is not giving perfect height so is there any other way to calculate dynamic height of label. Thanks.

Comment: along with calculating the height of text (label), you have to override the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method of the UITableView delegate. You should calculate the height in that method. I hope then it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is worth looking at is the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier use in your code. from what i can tell you are creating a new cell for each data item because you are using the cell section and row as and identifier. Is there a reason for this? If your cells are visually the same (Only the data for each is different) then change this so the dequeueReusableCell identifier is the same for each cell. This gives the OS the ability to manage the memory for cells more efficiently.